# Compute real and imaginary part of parametrized complex rational expression

Tags: complex, algebraic-manipulation

I would like to compute the real and imaginary part of a complex valued rational function $Z_b=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\frac{1}{C_1 \text{i$\omega $}}+L \text{i$\omega $}+R}+C_2 \text{i$\omega $}}$ that depends on parameters $R,C_1,C_2,L,\omega$ which are all real.

$Z_b$ is defined in the notebook code below:

```
Subscript[Z, a] := s*L + 1/(s*Subscript[C, 1]) + R
Zb := 1/(1/Subscript[Z, a] + s*Subscript[C, 2])
Subscript[Z, b] := Zb /. s -> I\[Omega]
$Assumptions = 
 L > 0 && R > 0 && Subscript[C, 1] > 0 && 
  Subscript[C, 2] > 0 && \[Omega] > 0
ComplexExpand[Subscript[Z, b]]
```

Now I am not completely sure which functions I could use for this. I tried using `ComplexExpand` but that did not seem to give me the desired result and instead simply gave me back the definition of $Z_b$.

Comment: `C[1]` etc are reserved symbols.  In general, it is better not to begin the names of user  variables with capital letters.

Comment: `ComplexExpand` does not take the option `Assumptions` so you need to include `FullSimplify`, i.e., `ComplexExpand[ReIm[Subscript[Z, b]]] // FullSimplify`

Answer (score 3):

You get a much simple form and better overview applying Together some times.

```
$Assumptions = 
L > 0 && R > 0 && Subscript[C, 1] > 0 && 
Subscript[C, 2] > 0 && \[Omega] > 0;

Subscript[Z, a] = s*L + 1/(s*Subscript[C, 1]) + R // Together;

Zb = 1/(1/Subscript[Z, a] + s*Subscript[C, 2]) // Together;

Subscript[Z, b] = Zb /. s -> I \[Omega];

ce = ComplexExpand[Through[{Re, Im}[Subscript[Z, b]]], 
     TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] // Simplify
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve this issue by adjusting `/. s -> I\[Omega]` to `/. s -> I*\[Omega]` and simply calling `ComplexExpand`.

```
Subscript[Z, a] := s*L + 1/(s*Subscript[C, 1]) + R
Zb := 1/(1/Subscript[Z, a] + s*Subscript[C, 2])
Subscript[Z, b] := Zb /. s -> I*\[Omega]
ComplexExpand[Subscript[Z, b]]
```

I then manually copied the real and imaginary part to a new cell where I called `Simplify` on the expression.